# foldl and IO values

Tags: haskell, io, fold

I have such code:

```
foldl (\a x -> a ++ (f x)) [] list
```

All seems to be ok, but `(f x) :: IO [String]`, and `(++)` gives an error ([String] != IO [String]).

How to define empty IO[String] list? I can't make clean (f x).

Comment: Can you explain what you want your function to do?

Comment: I just want to add IO [String] to accumulation argument in fold(l)

Comment: (You can `++` lists, but you can't `++` IO values.) I was asking _why_ you wanted to do this - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want to make an empty `IO [String]`, then you could do `return []`, since `return` brings any value into `IO` (or rather it brings any value into whatever monad you require). But, as AndrewC notes, that will not help you, since `(++)` cannot take `IO` lists, but only pure lists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The combinator you want here is probably

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t foldM
foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

and with that

```
foldM (\a x -> fmap (a++) (f x)) [] list
```

to run the actions `f x` in sequence and accumulate the `[String]`s they produce.

Comment: This concatenates the lists the inefficient left-associated way.

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
foldl (\a x -> a ++ (f x)) [] list
```

you're trying to do `a ++ f x` but `f x :: IO [String]`, so it's not working. Let's see if we can work out what's going on.

You mean for `x` to come from your `list`, so you'll be applying `f` in turn to each of the elements of the list, and they each give you a `[String]` and you want to concatenate them together as you go along.

We'll use `mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`, which maps a function over a list then sequences the monad operations together into one, combining the outputs into a list.

```
concatMapM :: (a -> IO [String]) -> [a] -> IO [String]
concatMapM f list = fmap concat (mapM f list)
```

Here I've used `fmap` to apply the pure function `concat` to the result of the IO operation.

You could test it out using

```
fileLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
fileLines filename = fmap lines (readFile filename)
```

```
*Main> concatMapM fileLines ["test1.txt","test2.txt"]
["This is test1.txt","It has two lines.","This is test2.txt","It has two lines too."]
```

This way is better than trying to foldl, because `concat` works more efficiently than `foldl (++)`. To check this out for yourself, compare these for speed:

```
*Main> writeFile "test3.txt" $ foldl (++) [] (map show [1..10000])
*Main> writeFile "test3.txt" $ foldr (++) [] (map show [1..10000])
```

The trouble is that `foldl` does `(((a++b)++c)++d)++e` so runs through the list `a` four times - it runs through it first as it adds `b`, then it runs through `a` and `b` as it adds `c`, then it runs through `a`, `b` and `c` as it adds `d`, then runs through all four of them as it adds `e`. This is a big waste of effort.

`foldr` does `a ++ (b ++ (c ++ (d ++ e)))` so runs through each list once - `d` then `c` then `b` then `a`. `concat` is a `foldr`, which is much better for this list operation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following:

```
list :: [a]
f :: a -> IO b
```

I assume that you want to get a final value of type `IO [b]`. If you map `f` over `list`, you get a list of type `[IO b]`. You can "move the IO" from the inside to the outside using `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` like this:

```
sequence (map f list) :: IO [b]
```

Think of it this way: before the sequencing, you had a list of instructions for making a value of type `b`. Now you have a single instruction for making a list of `b`'s.